# How to increase the processing performance of netfilter queue in userspace?

Tags: performance, queue, kernel, netfilter

I wonder how to speed up my packet filter program based on libnetfilter_queue , a library allow handling packet in userspace netfilter queue.

I think the key point is that the switching between userspace and kernelspace is slow.For increasing the performance , must I rewrite my program as a patch of the kernel and run it in kernelspace? thx.

Comment: @user1495181 sry, I didn't find good solution.A opensource project , L7-filter have stopped development for years. The cost of switch between userspace and kernalspace cannot be reduced by simply using libnetfilter_queue as I know.

Comment: Do you have any references to the cost of switch between kernel space to user space ? Did you tried the performance tips that they give in the documentation

Comment: @user1495181 Our team have tried 1,2,4 tips of the five, but the improvement is not comfortable.I think you can try the 5th tip.Finally,our client reduced their requirement, so we didn't actually make it.